# Percent of time that number will spawn

Tags: python, random, probability

So I have a program to spawn numbers in 2048. Right now the chances of a 2 or 4 spawning are 50/50.

```
nlist = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
def spawnnum():
    x = []
    for i in range(0, 16):
        if nlist[i] == 0:
            x.append(nlist[i])
    y = random.randint(1, len(x))
    count = 0
    for j in range(len(nlist)):
        if nlist[j] == 0:
            count += 1
        if count == y:
            nlist[j] = 2 * random.randint(1, 2)
            break
```

Is there a way of making the program so that the chances of a 4 spawning is 10% of the time and a 2 spawning is 90% of the time. BTW the place where this program actually spawns the number is `nlist[j] = 2 * random.randint(1, 2)`(Second to last line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very easy way is:

```
            nlist[j] = random.choice((4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks, Im so dumb to not think of this.

Answer (score 2):

Given there are only two options you can simply do:

```
if random.random() <= 0.1:
    nlist[j] = 4
else: 
    nlist[j] = 2
```

You can do something similar to your single expression but I wouldn't recommend it based on readability:

```
nlist[j] = 2 * ((random.random() <= 0.1) + 1)
```